# Java - Jar could not find included libraries and main class

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I am currently trying to make a Jar with all my libraries included. What I have done, I have created folders like this :

```
eancopy (which contain all my classes)
lib (containing all my libraries : mongo, jedis...)
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

My main class is named `process` (within the package eancopy)

My manifest is like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Class-Path: lib\commons-pool-1.5.6.jar lib\jedis-2.0.0.jar lib\mongo-2.6.3.jar
Created-By: 1.6.0_24-b07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: eancopy.process
```

I have generated the JAR with this command :

```
jar cvmf META-INF/MANIFEST.MF EANcopy.jar eancopy/*.class lib/*.jar
```

My problem : When executing the JAR by `java -jar EANcopy.jar`, it works when it is executed in the place where I have generated the JAR but in another place I have the message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.DBObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: eancopy.process. Program will exit.
```

Any ideas ?  Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to accept answers?

Answer (score 0):

This exception shows you the cause of the problem:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBObject

You haven't specified these libs `lib\commons-pool-1.5.6.jar lib\jedis-2.0.0.jar lib\mongo-2.6.3.jar` in your `CLASSPATH` environment variable, hence why it fails when run in other places.

Comment: It's specified in the MANIFEST -> Class-Path, for compatbility I prefer not using CLASSPATH environment variable

Comment: Yes, but are all these jars included in the `EANCopy.jar`?